Ethernet signal from STM32H7 to LAN8742A good, link good, receive good, no transmit
I am working with a custom board based on the NUCLEO STM32H745. The STM32H745 will receive a broadcast ping and ARP. It will try to respond to the ARP and disregard the broadcast ping. I can trace the response to the ARP up to the PHY, but nothing is received on the other end (PC).
The PHY auto negotiates 100M full duplex. It is receiving data and getting it to the microcontroller. There is a carrier on the transmit and receive pair.
What's left that could be wrong? Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Other things checked:

7499010121A integrated magnetics are used instead of discrete, checked the pinouts
scoped the signal along the cable, signal on both pairs
tried 10M full and half duplex, link lights respond but still nothing received at other end 10M is working on multiple cards. I'm not sure why it did not work the first time.
wireshark sees no packets
switch will not route pings since no ARP is received by the switch, wired direct, still no packets get to PC
routes are balanced


Added schematics. I don't think it's on the MCU side since I can scope the TX and RX data to the PHY. I can see the ARP and response in the debugger. I can also scope the RJ45 for signals when there is no cable connected.
I have this problem with 2 PCBs.

Since the 10M works and 100M does not, I am assuming there is something wrong with the voltage levels and/or rise fall time of the signal. At 100M the rise time is ~7ns and the voltage is ~1.4v p-p. Not sure what about the circuit is making the LAN8742A to perform below spec.

There is no schematics to verify. Also if one board does this, it may be a PCB manufacturing or soldering error instead of design error.

I updated the post with schematic of the ethernet side. This problem exists on the 2 PCBs I have checked. It could be the whole batch, but electrically, the signal goes all the way RJ45 - RX magnetics - PHY - MCU - PHY. I don't know how to verify that the data is going out the PHY - TX magnetics - RJ45, but I can verify the typical signal is there when the cable is disconnected. Also, the link negotiates. So, I assume the PHY - TX magnetics - RJ45 is connected properly.

I am experiencing a similar problem. I can see that TXD0 and TXD1 signals together with TX_ENA are sent by the MCU to LAN8742, but no transmit signal at TXP, TXN outputs. The receive seems working fine. Please share when you solve this.

10M started working. I still do not know root cause. If you look at the debug, you may find that the packet is being ignored by the program. if the device can never announce itself, the switch will never send it a ping message.
